# Powershell: Get Eventlogs Based on Date Range

Tags: powershell, date-range, event-viewer

The below Powershell script works great. It goes into my eventviewer log, captures all events for a particular eventid in the last 24 hours and exports it to a temp file. I am now trying to modify this script, so that it will only show me data from the following date range (Jan. 7, 2020 - Feb. 6, 2020). For the life of me I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how to add date range?

```
Get-WinEvent -ProviderName $ProviderName -MaxEvents 64000 -EA SilentlyContinue | Where-Object 
  $_.id -in $EventID -and $_.Timecreated -gt (Get-date).AddHours(-24)
} | Sort TimeCreated -Descending | Export-Csv $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `$_.id -in $EventID`, I gather that variable `$EventID` is an array of event id's. If not and this is a single event id, change the `-in` into `-eq`.

To get the creation date in a range, you can do:

```
$startDate = (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 1 -Day 7).Date   # .Date makes it midnight
$endDate   = (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 2 -Day 6).Date

Get-WinEvent -ProviderName $ProviderName -MaxEvents 64000 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object { $_.id -in $EventID -and $_.Timecreated -ge $startDate -and $_.Timecreated -lt $endDate } |
    Sort-Object TimeCreated -Descending | Export-Csv $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Seeing that there was some misunderstanding about the usage of `.Date`, a small explanation:

Using the `.Date` property means you discard the current time and get the date at midnight, because at that exact moment a date changes over.

The above code will filter between the start date **inclusive** and the end date **exclusive**, so all events created from *Jan. 7 2020 00:00:00* up to, **but not including** *Feb. 6 2020* will be returned.
In this case, the last event returned could be at *Feb. 5 2020 23:59:59*.

If you want the events returned to **include** the end date, simply add 1 day to it as in

```
$endDate = (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 2 -Day 6).Date.AddDays(1)
```

Now, all events created from *Jan. 7 2020 00:00:00* up to, **but not including** *Feb. 7 2020* will be returned. (including all events that happened on Feb. 6 2020).
In this case, the last event returned could be at *Feb. 6 2020 23:59:59*.

Hope that explains.

Comment: As written, your end date will truncate any events that happen on that date. It's likely that OP wants the events from the end date as well.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Yes, that's up to the OP. If the endDate is supposed to be in the collection aswell, it should be set to `(Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 2 -Day 7).Date`. Simply play around with the range. Taking the date as midnight, releaves you from adding the time part. This is especially useful for people like me who live in a part of the world that is not using `AM` and `PM`.

Comment: The `.Date` property doesn't fix this. If you want the whole day, either add one day if you want to use the `.Date` property (sets time to midnight) or specify 11:59:59 PM as the time along with the date.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest ..That's what I said.. So for me, yes the `.Date` makes it a lot easier. Maybe for the OP aswell.

Comment: Ah I misread your comment, you added the extra day to your statement

Answer (score 1):

In your `Where-Object` clause, you need to check for `$_.TimeCreated` being both greater than `Jan. 7, 2020 12:00:00 AM` and less than `Feb. 6, 2020 11:59:59 PM`:

```
$startTime = Get-Date -Date "Jan. 7, 2020 12:00:00 AM"
$endTime = Get-Date -Date "Feb. 6, 2020 11:59:59 PM"

Get-WinEvent .... | Where-Object {
  $_.id -eq $EventID -and $_.TimeCreated -ge $startTime -and $_.TimeCreated -le $endTime
}
```

This works because while `Get-Date -Date` expects a `DateTime` object, PowerShell knows how to implicitly convert properly formatted date strings into a `DateTime` object. Then, you just need to make sure that the `TimeCreated` property of each event falls between both the lower and upper bounds.

---

See this article for more information about how PowerShell's ["Type Conversion Magic"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/) works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builltin filters to do it, and it will be even faster.  To get over the 256 limit of the lognames, use a foreach loop.  Same with over 846 providernames.  It's already sorted in timecreated descending.  Wow, this can return up to 1151 events.

```
get-winevent @{ providername = 'esent'; id = 916;
  starttime = '1/7'; endtime = '2/6' } -MaxEvents 3


   ProviderName: ESENT

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
2/5/2020 11:09:00 PM           916 Information      svchost (3120,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.
2/5/2020 10:08:59 PM           916 Information      svchost (3120,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.
2/5/2020 9:08:00 PM            916 Information      svchost (3120,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.
```